# Can a bacterium survive without GroEL protein?

Tags: proteins, protein-folding

In prokaryotes, GroEL protein (together with GroES) is required for protein folding.

Question: Can a bacterium survive without GroEL protein?

Answer (score 4):

In E. coli, GroEL/GroES is found to interact with about 10% of all soluble proteins (Kerner et al. Cell 2005) and is the only chaperone essential to the bacterium under all tested conditions (Horwich et al. Cell 1993).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't appear to be a knockout for it in the Keio collection (they systematically knocked out genes in E coli to assess essentiality, via recombineering).

If they couldn't knock it out, that strongly suggests it's an essential gene and the organism cannot survive without it.

http://cgsc.biology.yale.edu/KeioList.php

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1681482/

Comment: There is a groEL knockout: http://cgsc2.biology.yale.edu/Strain.php?ID=109235

Comment: That's only a GroL knockout, so I'd say the point still stands.

Comment: I'm fairly sure groL and groEL are synonyms.

Comment: You may be right, I assumed they were a pair, but I think I'm confusing this with it's interaction with ES.

If so, I stand corrected.

And that nomenclature is stupid :p

Comment: Haha agreed. Also, in the page I linked to: "There is some question as to if this strain has a complete knockout of groL".

Comment: Yeah I know with the KC they've been plagued by false results.